# The line between asking and googling

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I used to google for solutions for days and days until I found the solution.  Looking back now, I think that was a bit too much googling.  Now, I'm starting to just ask on stackoverflow and not google it at all.  Is there an FAQ describing how much you should google, or is it based totally on my personal opinion and it's not a question?

Comment: You mean you don't even use the site search beforehand?

Comment: I use the search that automatically pops up when I ask a question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my eyes, the ideal approach when you have a question is:

- If available, search the documentation (Thanks @Carlos)
- Google. Try a few variations of your search.
- Search on SO. Try a few variations of your search.
- Once you have done that, and not found anything that you feel helps you, **then** ask on SO, but not earlier.

Asking something that could easily have been Googled is **not** a deadly sin, but try to avoid it. Otherwise, at some point, people start feeling like they're being used as mechanical turks for Googling, which is not the sites' point.

Comment: This makes the same assumption that the OP is making: that Google doesn't index SO.  Odd.

Comment: @Hans Why do you say that?

Comment: @Hans when I see a question about a basic function (like, "how do I lowercase a string?") - and typing the question title into Google gives you **the authoritative reference documentation** with 100% certainty - I don't *care* whether it gets indexed by Google or not. It is not a question that should be on SO, and asking it is just abuse of the site. There *are* questions that shouldn't be asked, but Googled. *Edit:* maybe I misunderstood what you meant, in that case @Kragen is saying what I would say

Comment: @Hans The Google and SO search often return completely different results, for example try searching for "Using Beautiful soup from IronPython".  The Google search does contain *some* SO results, but none of the ones that appears for the same search on SO.  I often use google with `site:stackoverflow.com`, as the results are often more useful than the SO search results.

Comment: Even Google returns different results from Google.  Happens when you query it differently.  Which is what you'd do when you research a question for more than, say, 10 minutes.  If none of these queries turns up anything at SO then there's little point in searching SO separately.  Ymmv.

Comment: Now searching **"how do I lowercase a string"** in Google, give me this post though :P

Comment: @Kragen, what you're saying simply establishes that Google and SO use different search algorithms. That's not exactly surprising and the `:site` suffix to a google search is useful for other things as well, including MSDN. The MSDN bit *is* surprising because it's run by a company that also has `bing`, a search engine.

Comment: The 1st step should be to search (in) the documentation if applicable. It's obvious, but some programmers *forget* it to easily.

Comment: @Carlos very good point, added.

Comment: Robots.txt on MSO indexes the answered questions only (and a few other things).